# Programa para verificar si una variable introducida por el usuario es par o impar

Tags: c++

Quería crear una función donde verificara si el número introducido por el usuario es impar e imprima un mensaje.

Lamentablemente me da los siguientes errores.

```
Main.cpp:4:5: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
  n % 2;
  ~ ^ ~
Main.cpp:5:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
Main.cpp:9:19: error: unexpected ';' before ')'
  int isEven(int a;){
                  ^
Main.cpp:9:21: error: function definition is not allowed here
  int isEven(int a;){
                    ^
Main.cpp:18:2: error: expected '}'
}
 ^
Main.cpp:6:11: note: to match this '{'
int main(){
          ^
2 warnings and 3 errors generated.
```

Adjunto código.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int isEven(int n){
  n % 2;
}
int main(){
  int a;
  cin >> a;
  int isEven(int a;){
  if (a == 0){
    cout << "The given value is even";
  }
  else{
    cout << "The given value is not even";
    {
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Es normal que te de error, `isEven` no devuelve nada, le pasas parámetro con fin de expresión (`;`) y las llaves ni siquiera cuadran.

Comment: Puedes [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/312042/edit) indicando qué error te daba así podría ser de utilidad en el futuro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que debes igualar a cero es la funcion `isEven()` , además dentro de la funcion `main()` no debes volver a abrir la funcion `isEven()`, debes inicializar la funcion antes de usarla y debes indicar que devuelves con un `return` quedaria tal que así.

```
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int isEven(int n);
int isEven(int n){
  return n % 2;
}
int main(){
  int a;
  cin >> a;

  if (isEven(a) == 0){
    cout << "The given value is even";
  }
  else{
    cout << "The given value is not even";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

también puedes hacer que la función isEven retorne un bool y se fije directamente 
dentro de la función si el numero n%2==0.
Quedaría de esta forma:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isEven(int n);
bool isEven(int n) {
    return ((n % 2) == 0);
}
int main() {
    int a;
    cin >> a;

    if (isEven(a)) {
        cout << "The given value is even";
    }
    else {
        cout << "The given value is not even";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Espero que te ayude.

Saludos